# How to check availability between two time set in java

Tags: java, android, data-structures, time

How can I check the given time set is available for already booked time in java.I store the time in "**yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss**" format in an array list from json response.
**For example tickets are booked for the following time and a new customer is requesting ticket in the time how can I check the tickets availability from already booked time.**

**Sample tickets already booked time:**

```
time set 1
        start time  "2013-11-11 08:10:00";
        end time    "2013-11-11 10:03:00";
time set 2          
        start time  "2013-11-11 14:11:00";
        end time    "2013-11-11 16:10:00";

time set 3      
        start time  "2013-11-11 11:00:00";
        end time    "2013-11-11 12:10:00";

time set 4          
        start time  "2013-11-11 19:00:00";
        end time    "2013-11-11 23:30:00";
```

**scenario 1:**

A new customer request ticket for the following time (**available time**):

```
    start time  "2013-11-11 10:04:00";
    end time    "2013-11-11 10:59:00";
```

**this time set is available because there is no time is booked in particular time.**

**scenario 2:**

A new customer request ticket for the following time (**Unavailable time**):

```
    start time  "2013-11-11 09:55:00";
    end time    "2013-11-11 10:59:00";
```

**this time set is unavailable because *09:55:00* is already booked in *time set 1***

**scenario :**

A new customer request ticket for the following time (**Unavailable time**):

```
    start time  "2013-11-11 10:20:00"
    end time    "2013-11-11 11:20:00"
```

**this time set is unavailable because *11:20:00* is already booked in *time set 3***

I store the json result in array list with following method:

```
    DateFormat formate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    ArrayList<Date> dealStart = new ArrayList<Date>();
    ArrayList<Date> dealEnd = new ArrayList<Date>();

    dealStart.add(formate.parse(jsonObject.getString("booked_start_time"));
    dealEnd.add(formate.parse(jsonObject.getString("booked_end_time"));
```

Please help me to solve the logic problem in java /android.

Comment: You forgot one scenario: from 8:00:00 to 11:00:00 is also unavailable.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how many "already booked tickets" will be in your data set? Are we talking about 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc?

Comment: @Justin, The no of booked ticket for the particular date is depends on user booking.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more straight forward ways to do it without a new data structure but [Interval Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) are used to accomplish your goal.

> In computer science, an interval tree is an ordered tree data
>   structure to hold intervals. Specifically, it allows one to
>   efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or
>   point.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/IntervalTree.java) is a Java implementation of an Interval Tree.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have a logic problem, but I strongly suggest you consider [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to manage Java/Android times and anything time related. Time is hard to do right, there are a lot of things you're not thinking (Timezones, Daylight savings, etc.), not to mention that the Joda Time is very straight forward and a lot easier to use and understand than the Java standards.

Since your application seems to be very time-dependent, this is a good idea.

Now back to your logic. With Joda it would be a matter of creating [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) instances for your booked times, and one for your requested ticket time and performing some time math. You can also use the more abstract [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html).

It should be relatively easy and very straight forward.

Example:

```
DateTime bookedstart = new DateTime(2013, 10, 25, 13, 0, 0, 0); //13:00
DateTime bookedend = new DateTime(2013, 10, 25, 14, 0, 0, 0);   //14:00
Interval interval = new Interval(bookedstart, bookedend);
DateTime requested = new DateTime(2013, 10, 25, 15, 45, 0, 0); //15:45
System.out.println(interval.contains(requested)); // false, so it's available.
```

Comment: what is DateTime class? its not available in java.

Comment: Click the Joda-Time link. ;)

Comment: Suppose DateTime requested = new DateTime(2013, 10, 25, 13, 0, 0, 0); I get true (that is unavailable). but the time is not between the interval. is the any do it in by Interval  class. please help.

Comment: 13:00:00 on October 25th, 2013 is between the above interval (bookedstart at that exact time). Try ```DateTime requested = new DateTime(2013, 10, 25, 12, 59, 0, 0);``` That should evaluate to false given the above.